# How to fetch the uploaded device name using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working in a website were I need to show the user the device name from which the user has uploaded the image ( Desktop, Iphone, Android etc. ). Can any one suggest me how can I achive this using Javascript.

Comment: Look at this it may help you [Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Dont know a way to detect the device itself, but you can find the os and browser version if that helps?

links:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9514476/6638478

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11219680/6638478