# How to change CSS according to user Operating System

Tags: css, html, google-app-engine, responsive-design, less

How can i write CSS that handle a different effect on Mac OS and different on other OS versions.

i.e.

```
.(mac){
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
}


 .(win and linux){
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: You could check the OS (or actually, browser `user agent` wich tells you its OS) with JavaScript, and dynamically load your CSS files

Comment: Ok big thanks, let me give it a short.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219582/how-to-detect-my-browser-version-and-operating-system-using-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with pure CSS, you can detect OS like MAX or WIN with JavaScript, and then use that to load different CSS styles.

You can use the result of `window.navigator` to find information about the OS.

```js
console.log(window.navigator);
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. console.log( window.navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Mac') ) would work best.