# How to change css style on a site depending on the user's OS?

Tags: javascript, css

How do I follow one cursor for Windows users and another one for MacOSX users?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change CSS according to user Operating System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39012649/how-to-change-css-according-to-user-operating-system) <=> interesting how similar those two titles are

Comment: If there was a way to reliably do that, that would be a big privacy concern.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. Check user platform in `navigator`. Then do something like:

```
if ( navigator.platform == "Win32" ) {
    // apply css-styling of cursor.
    document.getElementById("body").style.cursor = "progress";
}
```

The possible values are:

- MacIntel
- MacPPC
- Mac68K
- Win32
- Win16
- SunOS
- HP-UX
- Linux i686

Supported browsers:

- Google Chrome
- Internet Explorer & Edge
- Firefox
- Opera
- Safari