# Is a 2nd <source> tag required for image fallback in HTML?

Tags: html, image, webp, fallback, srcset

What is the proper way to do, for example, a WebP fallback to JPG inside an HTML `<picture>` tag?

Is it this (as in this StackOverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39338181):

```
<picture>
    <source type="image/webp" srcset="image.webp">
    <img src="image.jpg">
</picture>
```

-- or (as shown on css-tricks https://css-tricks.com/using-webp-images/#using-webp-in-html) --

```
<picture>
    <source type="image/webp" srcset="image.webp">
    <source type="image/jpeg" srcset="image.jpg">
    <img src="image.jpg">
</picture>
```

All I can find is conflicting information...

Comment: #2 isn’t exactly wrong, but I don’t see a reason not to do #1.

Comment: I like to consult mdn for these kind of questions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture

Comment: So, given that MDN shows #1, that must be the proper, most compatible way, correct? css-tricks' preferring #2 made me question this.