# Detect Windows XP in Firefox with JS

Tags: javascript, firefox, internet-explorer-8, windows-xp

I am using the following code to detect if the client has Windows XP:

```
if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Windows NT 5.1') > -1)
        $('#isXP').modal('show');
```

This works perfectly on Chrome and IE. But not in IE8 and Firefox.

Any idea how can I detect it?

Comment: Try this reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219582/how-to-detect-my-browser-version-and-operating-system-using-javascript

Comment: The solution of this example has the same code as mine, and assumes the code works in all browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also you navigator.userAgent, like so:

```
navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Windows NT 5.1') != -1
```

Comment: This code worked on FireFox, thank you.
navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Windows NT 5.1') != -1