# Detect Windows-like or Mac-like keyboard in Javascript

Tags: javascript, operating-system, user-agent, modifier-key

My web app has a feature where the user can hold Ctrl (Windows, `ctrlKey`) or Cmd (Mac, `metaKey`). I want to provide help text telling the user they can do this.

What's a reliable way to detect a Mac-like keyboard? Is `navigator.platform.match(/mac/i)` safe enough?

Comment: What about `hold Ctrl (Windows) or Cmd (Mac)` as help text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect my browser version and operating system using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219582/how-to-detect-my-browser-version-and-operating-system-using-javascript)

Comment: @marekful That's a starting point, but I don't think it's great UX to provide irrelevant information to users when you can do better.

Comment: The Apple command key is a non standard modifier and as such is implemented with different keycode values in different browsers. You can however detect OS from User-Agent.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be reliable:

```
const isMac = navigator.userAgent.includes('Mac');
```