# How can you detect the full version of a browser?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, browser

I found the code detect the browser and version , but i am searching full version

```
Example :

navigator.sayswho= (function(){
    var ua= navigator.userAgent, tem, 
    M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
    if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
        tem=  /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
        return 'IE '+(tem[1] || '' || tem[2]);
    }
    if(M[1]=== 'Chrome'){
        tem= ua.match(/\b(OPR|Edge)\/(\d+)/);
        console.log("eee",tem);
        if(tem!= null) return tem.slice(1).join(' ').replace('OPR', 'Opera');
    }
    M= M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if((tem= ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!= null) M.splice(1, 1, tem[1], tem[2]);
    return M.join(' ');
})();

console.log("ddddd",navigator.sayswho);
```

using above code browser and version getting, but not full version.

```
Chrome 70

IE 11 

how to get full version like 

Chrome 70.0.3538.102

IE 11.726.16299.0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you detect the version of a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/how-can-you-detect-the-version-of-a-browser)

Comment: @Ahmad: The code in OP's "this is _not_ what I want" example looks like it is taken from your dupe suggestion's answers.

Comment: check http://mrbool.com/how-to-detect-different-browsers-and-their-versions-using-javascript/25424

Comment: please check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219582/how-to-detect-my-browser-version-and-operating-system-using-javascript/11219680), i tried it and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are available to use third party JS library than you can try to make a test with **Platform JS**.

Example code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/platform/1.3.5/platform.min.js"></script>

<script>
console.log(platform);
document.write("You are using " + platform.name +
               " v" + platform.version + 
               " on " + platform.os);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Output with various browsers.

[image]

Comment: for other browser it getting fullversion . For IE it getting only version (IE11.0) expect IE 11.0.9256

Comment: @John Ken, I made a test with other JS libraries but no any library returns full version of IE.