# Redirect to a new windows, with JavaScript, with a onclick on <a></a>

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, href, user-agent

I was making this code to insert it into my website, to detect the OS from the devices, and depending which OS they have, redirect to different pages. Also, if I upload the code to my website, the href doesn't work really well, and it searches https://example.com/thehref instead of the href alone.

This is what I have been doing, to solve the problem.

```html
<script>

  var OSName = "Unknown OS";
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Win") != -1) OSName = 1;
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mac") != -1) OSName = 0;
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Linux") != -1) OSName = 1;
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Android") != -1) OSName = 1;
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("like Mac") != -1) OSName = 0;

    if (OSName == 1) OSName = "play.google.com";
    if (OSName == 0) OSName = "apps.apple.com";


</script>

<a href="https://www.google.com" onclick="location.href=this.href+OSName;return false;"> <p>Click<br> at me!!!</p> </a>
```

And my idea is that every time someones click on it, it redirects them to another page, I have been searching, and it seems that onclik and target="_blank" don't work well together.

If someone knows how to solve the problem, or has an idea, feel free to comment.

Thx you all. :)

Comment: please understand that Java and JavaScript are not the same

Comment: @Stultuske, sorry I don't know the difference between, in this case what am I using?

Comment: The above code is Javascript. It might be worth knowing that it is very easy to `"spoof"` the `userAgent` string so this method is never going to be 100% reliable

Comment: He only said that because of the tag, ok. I thought I said something wrong in my question.

Comment: Is there something more reliable, than userAgent, in this case? @ProfessorAbronsius

Comment: Have a [read through this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219582/how-to-detect-my-browser-version-and-operating-system-using-javascript) or [this](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one.

```
<script>
  var OSName = "Unknown OS";

  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Win") != -1) OSName = 1;
  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mac") != -1) OSName = 0;
  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Linux") != -1) OSName = 1;
  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Android") != -1) OSName = 1;
  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("like Mac") != -1) OSName = 0;

  if (OSName == 1) OSName = "page1";
  if (OSName == 0) OSName = "page2";

  function openPage() {
    window.open(window.location.href + '/' + OSName);
    return false;
  }
</script>

<a href="https://" onclick="openPage()"> <p>Click<br> at me!!!</p> </a>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for giving me another option, but with the first one, it works fine. You just need to keep in mind, that if you don't put anything in the href camp, it will block the first page.

Comment: It has to be a valid link, inside the href.

Answer (score 1):

You can create another `<a>` tag and call `click()` in JS

```
    var OSName = "Unknown OS";
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Win") != -1) OSName = 1;
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mac") != -1) OSName = 0;
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Linux") != -1) OSName = 1;
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Android") != -1) OSName = 1;
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("like Mac") != -1) OSName = 0;
  
    if (OSName == 1) OSName = "play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gecose.appseguros360.irgmediassegur";
    if (OSName == 0) OSName = "apps.apple.com/es/app/irg-mediassegur/id1509456102";
  
    function onClick() {
        let a = document.createElement('a')
        a.setAttribute('href', 'https://'+OSName)
        a.setAttribute('target', '_blank')
        a.click()
    }
</script>
<a onclick="onClick()" > <p>Click<br> at me!!!</p> </a>
```

Comment: If you want to avoid, that the original page gets blocked, you just need to fill the hrerf, in my case I put the same link where you click on this link. And it works perfect.

Comment: It has to be a valid link, inside the href.