# How to get Profile info from Google Signin with redirect mode (no-popup)?

Tags: javascript, html, google-signin

Here's how I do it, after getting the signin's client file :

```
// HTML 
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js" async defer></script>
```

I called `gapi.load()` function into a HTML button

```
// load the startApp function after the page loads
jQuery(function () {
    $(window).load(function () {
       startApp()
    })
})


var startApp = function () {

    gapi.load('auth2', function () {

        // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
            ux_mode: 'redirect',      // I don't want it to display a pop-up 
            scope: 'profile email'    // I just need to get user's name, profile picture and email address
        });

        // attach this function into a button element with id = "customBtn"
        attachSignin(document.getElementById('customBtn'));

    });
};

function attachSignin(element) {
    auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
        function (googleUser) {

            // it never calls this block of code.
            // this never runs
            console.log(googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName())
            var gProfile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
            var name = gProfile.getName();
            var email = gProfile.getEmail();
            var imgUrl = gProfile.getImageUrl();
        }, function (error) {
            return alert("Google Sign in error!")
        });
}
```

It load the necessary functions into a button. If user click on that button, user will be redirected into Google's signin page. After user manages to sign in then Google will redirect the URL back into my website.

It **should** also send the user's profile info into my `attachClickHandler()` function within the `attachSignin()`. But it never happens since it reloads the page before the handler function gets called.
It only works if I change the `ux_mode: 'redirect'` into default' `popup`

The best I can do right now is just to get the email address from the `token_id` parameter that Google give in URL after signin. The `id_token` field from the URL is a jwt that can be decoded

`http://localhost:3006/login#scope=email%20profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20openid&id_token=xxxxxxxxx&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com`

So How to get the user's profile information with `ux_mode` set to `redirect` ?

Comment: I can't believe it... it seems nobody knows how to get the user's profile information if `ux_mode` is set to `redirect` / no-popup

Comment: what's it mean ? The code above works fine if `ux_mode` is set to `redirect`. User can input their email / password and then Google redirects user back into my website with additional parameters in URL.. The problem is I cannot get profile information from `id_token` and `client_id` alone

Comment: As I can see from docs ux_mode has 2 options pop up and redirect. So you don't want to use ux_mode? and just use token_id and client id. Right?

Comment: I actually do not care about `token_id` or `client_id` as long as it can provide me with user profile (photo, email, name, etc). If both variable can be used to get the user profile, then I will gladly accept it as the answer

Comment: Ok, check my answer and let me know, also read the link that I have provided.

Comment: OK. Thank you. I'll try your answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I modified your code so it works:**

```
var startApp = function () {

    gapi.load('auth2', function () {

        // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
            ux_mode: 'redirect',      // I don't want it to display a pop-up 
            scope: 'profile email'    // I just need to get user's name, profile picture and email address
        });

        // attach this function into a button element with id = "customBtn"
        attachSignin(document.getElementById('customBtn'));

        
        // START NEW CODE
        auth2.currentUser.listen(function(googleUser) {
            if (googleUser && (gProfile = googleUser.getBasicProfile())) {
                var name   = gProfile.getName();
                var email  = gProfile.getEmail();
                var imgUrl = gProfile.getImageUrl();

                console.log({name, email, imgUrl});
            }
        });
        // END NEW CODE

    });
};

// Can remove callbacks if not using pop-up
function attachSignin(element) {
    auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {});
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

When using redirect instead of pop-up, listen on `currentUser` instead of the `attachClickHandler()` callbacks. The Google API will detect and consume the redirect parameters, firing the `currentUser.listen` handler.

Sources:

- https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/477#issuecomment-430299619
- https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/listeners

Comment: YESSS!!! Clear-cut and to-the-point explanation. Also working code. It works! I hope this will help others too. Thank you sir!

Comment: I tested this method and I can confirm that it's working on windows and android but not Safari on ios. The `auth2.currentUser.listen` is called but the `googleUser` is empty. There's also a warning abut `The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''strict-dynamic''. It will be ignored.`

Comment: it seems that redirect mode and ` auth2.currentUser.listen()` is not working for safari for some reason. Both safari on MacOS desktop or mobile version do not work. Do you know what might cause it ? @Leftium

Comment: @DennyHiu I was able to reproduce on my iPhone, but it's difficult for me to debug because I don't have a Mac. It might be a Safari-specific problem? I suggest opening another question.

Comment: @DennyHiu It seems the redirect method no longer works in safari: "Due to the ITP policy, only the default popup flow works on Safari." (https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/589#issuecomment-793155811)

Comment: @DennyHiu Lots of more issues to explore: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+safari

Comment: @DennyHiu This is the closest issue. Unfortunately the solution seems to be to use the raw HTTP API (vs JS SDK): https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/566#issuecomment-577919436

Comment: I have macbook and its developer mode don't give any clear reason why. It just doesn't work. Maybe the best we can do is making a different version with `popup` flow in Safari

Comment: @DennyHiu The HTTP API seems to work: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow The JS SDK is just a convenience wrapper around the HTTP API.

Comment: How to do that ? would you mind to add example for HTTP API in your answer ?

Comment: @DennyHiu I already linked to this: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/566#issuecomment-577919436 It can be simplied to two steps: 1. Construct HTTP OAuth link. 2. Detect and handle URL params in redirect URL (3. Optionally call other API's with token to get more info)

Comment: it turns out that using "popup" for  iOS and MacOS is far easier solution for me. I just need to get the OS version from `navigator ` (explained in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219582/how-to-detect-my-browser-version-and-operating-system-using-javascript). And put a conditional check if it's a Mac or Safari the old `popup` mode will be used.