# Displaying Computer Browser

Tags: javascript, html

I am using javascript code shown below for displaying my computer browser as just "Firefox 19.0".

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function detect()
{
 document.getElementById("bCodeName").innerHTML = navigator.appCodeName;
}
</script>
<div id="bCodeName"></div>
<body onload="detect();"></body>
```

But this code is just displaying:

```
Mozilla
```

I have no idea how to go ahead.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open a `console` (Firebug or Chrome Console`) and type `Navigator` into the immediates jor command line.

Comment: why has this question been downvoted?

Comment: @imulsion. I didn't downvote, but I must say it shows little research effort. If one property doesn't return exactly what you want, you should be able to look up other properties of the same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously stated, you may browser through the "navigator" object properties and then properly parse the ones interesting for you (for example: "appCodeName", "appVersion" and the omnipresent "userAgent").

Two ways of doing so might be:

```
function detect()
{
    document.getElementById("bCodeName").innerHTML = navigator.appCodeName + " " + navigator.appVersion.split(" ")[0];
}
```

or a bit shorter:

```
function detect()
{
    document.getElementById("bCodeName").innerHTML = navigator.userAgent.split(" ")[0].replace("/", " ");
}
```

You may do well handling exceptions, in case there was some error whilst parsing this data. See [Javascript Try/Catch](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp)

**Edit:**

If you want to show the specific application name and version, take a look to [this great SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5918791/2186237). With this, the final code would be:

```
function detect()
{
    var N= navigator.appName, ua= navigator.userAgent, tem;
    var M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i);
    if(M && (tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
    M = M? [M[1], M[2]]: [N, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    document.getElementById("bCodeName").innerHTML = M[0] + " " + M[1]
}
```

Comment: Hi Shere...Thanks for that but it displays Mozilla 5.0 but I need Firefox 5.0. How to go ahead with this?

Comment: The answer has been just updated with the output you are looking for. Play a bit with this and see if this is what you were looking for. By the way, I think it would be better that "detect()" returned the version and you inserted this into the HTML outside -- this will make your code more usable in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use `navigator.appName` instead. I'm not sure if that returns the right name (it returns 'Netscape' in Chrome, for some reason. `navigator` also has [some other properties](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_navigator.asp) like `appVersion` that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by *kennebec* in [Browser detection in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript)

```
navigator.sayswho= (function(){
  var N= navigator.appName, ua= navigator.userAgent, tem;
  var M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i);
  if(M && (tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
  M= M? [M[1], M[2]]: [N, navigator.appVersion,'-?'];
  return M;
 })();
```

You may also use `navigator.userAgent`

Here is a complete Documentation:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp