# Check if the browser is Firefox

Tags: browser

I need to know if the browser running my page is Firefox.  I came across the code below:

```
 var isGecko = (navigator.product == 'Gecko');
```

but this is true for Firefox and Safari.

Comment: Don't.  Use feature detection instead.

Comment: This looks like it was already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript

Comment: SLaks, in a perfect world, I'll use nothing but feature detection. As long as things like Flash, webcam access, and other random things have weird behaviors between browsers in must-be-perfect environments...I'm going to keep regretfully browser-sniffing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only Firefox has the string "Firefox" in the user agent, so it is as easy as

```
var isFirefox = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') !== -1);
```

Edit: yes, [Mozilla discourages it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent)

Comment: This returns false to me in Mozilla Firefox. Might not be up to date?