# How to disable <meta> tag in firefox?

Tags: html, browser

How to set following tag to be inactive in `firefox` browser?

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="120"/>
```

The reason is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813761/meta-tag-refresh-page-firefox-and-chrome-difference)

Comment: For **IE** you can use conditional comments: `<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="120"/><![endif]-->`, [reference](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

Comment: The title of the question does not match its body. Is this about Chrome only, or about Chrome and IE only?

Comment: It's mainly for chrome.. sorry

Comment: After the edit, we don’t know whether the question is about Chrome or about Firefox. You should describe the original problem you are trying to solve, not an assumed way of solving an unspecified problem.

Comment: Hmm, there is a link to original problem in my question.. I try to find out any usable solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detecting browsers is [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2400957/1671639).  Though older version of jQuery support `$.browser()` it is not widely suggested.

Hence try to figure out the root cause of the problem and make it cross browser compatible.

**Updates:**

I have created a fiddle based using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9851769/1671639),

```
var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera') >= 0;
// Opera 8.0+ (UA detection to detect Blink/v8-powered Opera)
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';   // Firefox 1.0+
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
// At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
var isChrome = !!window.chrome;                          // Chrome 1+
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;                            // At least IE6

document.write('isFirefox: ' + isFirefox + '<br>');
document.write('isChrome: ' + isChrome + '<br>');
document.write('isSafari: ' + isSafari + '<br>');
document.write('isOpera: ' + isOpera + '<br>');
document.write('isIE: ' + isIE + '<br>');
```

Using the above browser detection code, I have added this

```
if (isFirefox) {
  $('meta[http-equiv=Refresh]').remove();    
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zxvE/369/)

Comment: Hmmm, it would be much better, but I don't know how

Comment: @gaffcz this means you don't to refresh in FF only

Comment: jop, because its behavior in FF is strange and I can't solve it

Answer (score 1):

If there is no conditional for chrome like for IE (like in comment above) than you can always check user agent on server side and add required `meta` tags if it is chrome.

Comment: Tjanks but I don't know how. Could you be more specific?