# Display div only in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm making a website at the moment and for some reason the z-index of a see through overlay is not working in internet explorer (it works in everything else), therefore I want to display a warning message that the website does not support internet explorer, how can I make a div with the class "Warning" show up only in internet explorer?

I am happy to this via any method (HTML, CSS, Jquery etc) as long as it either resolves the z-index issue or makes the warning div show.

Update: I had a friend of mine test my website and the conditional comments don't work in IE11, I want the div to be displayed in all versions of IE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a conditional statement to show the `div`:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <div class="warning">...</div>
<![endif]-->
```

This will work for all versions of IE, if you want to target specific versions, see [here](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) for more info.

EDIT: As GSerg has pointed out, this will only work for < IE11. For later versions of IE, you may have to rely on some JS like in this Q&A: [Browser detection in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript)

Comment: This did work for me in IE9, however a friend of mine just tested it in IE 11 and there was no warning for him.

Comment: @Aw555000 Correct, conditional comments are no longer processed in IE11+. Also the user agent string now says `Like Gecko`, which makes some web sites detect IE11 as a very old version of Firefox. Browser detection is bad for you :)

Comment: <!--[!if IE]>
    <div class="warning">...</div>
<![endif]-->
Will this work for all browsers that aren't IE?

Answer (score 1):

Html5 Boilerplate recommends this solution (checkout [this link](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html) for more details):

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your html in a conditional like so:

`<!--[if lt IE 7]>[html here]<![endif]-->`

the `lt` means 'less than'. You can target various version of IE by using `lt`, `gt` (greater than), `lte` (less than or equal to) and `gte` (greater than or equal to).