# how to set different height for different browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have div that has a `height: 300px;` and `overflow: auto;`. It looks good in Chrome, but in Firefox it start scroll the page. When I decrease the height to `height`: 200px;` it looks good.

Can we give different div height when html page open in Chrome and Firefox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use the below CSS block for firefox**

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
  .selector {
     width:200px;
  }
}
```

**and use the below CSS block for chrome**

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
 .selector {
     width:300px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write browser specific code by detecting browser.
Here is the link for browser detection [Browser detection in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Give the condition according to the browser using javascript

```
if (!!window.chrome == true) {
  //condition for chrome
 }
 else if (typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined') {
 //condition for firefox
 }
 else if (/*@cc_on!@*/false == true) {
       //condition for safari
    }
    else if (!!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera') >= 0) {
        //condition for opera
    }
    else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0) {
        //condition fo IE
    }
```

This javascript code will detect the browser. Give onload function for body and give the code for that function.

Answer (score 0):

Use different styles sheets (css) based on the browser.

E.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var browser=navigator.appName; 
    if browser == "Microsoft  Internet Explorer" 
    { 
        document.write("<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"IE.css\">"); 
    } 
    else if browser == "Firefox" 
    { 
        document.write("<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"Firefox.css\">"); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        document.write("<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"generic.css\">"); 
    } 
</script>
```

or

```
<!--[if IE]><link href="/ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
```

Comment: how can you please give one small exxample

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
var browser=navigator.appName;
if browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" {
document.write("<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"IE.css\">");
}
else if browser == "Firefox" {
document.write("<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"Firefox.css\">");
}
else {
document.write("<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"generic.css\">");
}
</script>

Comment: or <!--[if IE]><link href="/ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->

Comment: navigator.appName can't use here. Because for chrome, safari and firefox appName is Netscape.

Answer (score 0):

I think better way to change the css files based on the browser. As I think it is better to separate the styles functionality from the JavaScript. It will be good coding practice and maintainability will be easier.

Comment: can you give simple example