# Detect user's OS and rearrange/style download links

Tags: javascript

I have a website for an application I've developed, which is compiled for a variety of operating systems.  On the downloads page, I would like to have it arranged so that the download link for the user's OS is at the top with a big obvious "Download!" button, with the other options listed below in plainer links.  How can I do this?

Comment: Look into `navigator.userAgent` and the `User-Agent` header.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser detection in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you log `window` in Mozilla's developer console you can see all the properties of `window`, this is quite useful and fun to find new things.

When I did so there is a property called `navigator`, and within that `platform`.

So, since I was running Linux when I did this, the value of `window.navigator.platform` was equal to `"Linux"`.

One easy way you could do this is:

```
document.getElementById("download_btn").setAttribute("href","downloads/package_" + window.navigator.platform + ".zip");
```

So, if I were to download it off your site, I would download the file "package_Linux.zip".

Answer (score 0):

Type `navigator` in your javascript console and check out all the goodies you have access to. In particular, `userAgent` and `platform`.

Combine that with some regex matches and the help of [user agent strings list](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) and you're good to go.