# How to detect if a userscript is installed from the Chrome Store?

Tags: javascript, userscripts, tampermonkey, chrome-web-store

I want to notify the user when an update for my Greasemonkey/UserScript is available. However when the user has installed the script from the Chrome Web Store, I don't want to bother because it has auto-update functionality.

I first thought about using `$.browser==chrome` but it is also possible that a Chrome user has installed it using Tampermonkey. (Furthermore if the site would update jQuery, `$.browser` would stop working)

So, is it possible to detect that it is a UserScript installed through the Chrome Web Store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Probably best to just let the user know that an update is available, and not worry about the platform.**  Also it's not clear how cross-browser this script is.  You may have to resort to browser sniffing (not usually recommended) to be absolutely sure.

---

You can use [the `scriptHandler` property of the `GM_info` object](http://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_info), if you are only concerned about Chrome and/or Firefox:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Rough script handler detector
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// ==/UserScript==
var scriptEngine;

if (typeof GM_info === "undefined") {
    scriptEngine = "plain Chrome (Or Opera, or scriptish, or Safari, or rarer)";
    // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2401861/331508 for optional browser sniffing code.
}
else {
    scriptEngine = GM_info.scriptHandler  ||  "Greasemonkey";
}
console.log ('This userscript is running on ' + scriptEngine + '.');
```

Which yields:
**Tampermonkey:**

> This userscript is running on Tampermonkey.

**Greasemonkey (Strictly Firefox):**

> This userscript is running on Greasemonkey.

**Chrome from the web store, or other:**

> This userscript is running on plain Chrome (Or Opera, or scriptish, or Safari, or rarer).

Because only the big engines (Greasemonkey and Tampermonkey) currently support `GM_info`, if your userscript is especially cross-browser, you will need to do browser sniffing to differentiate in rarer cases.
[See this answer for browser-sniffing code that doesn't require jQuery.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2401861/331508)

---

<sub>Note: A `@grant` directive is not needed to use `GM_info`.</sub>