# show a div with jQuery if the user is on IE 9 and below

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

How could I detect (with jQuery) if the user is on IE 9 or below, and if they are `.show()` a div?

I have successfully done the below with jQuery for Android. **How could I do a IE 9 AND below condition**?

*Done similar with Android.* (would like a similar solution for *IE 9 **and** below*)

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {
    // alert( "welcome" );
    $("#android").slideDown();
}
```

Comment: can you try this? if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) < 9)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser detection in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript)

Comment: I'm looking for a short jQuery solution as Sushil is recommending, and like one i referenced, not a long old school javascript technique to isolate every browser user string, defining individually; but something simple, like if this or below.

Comment: you can also try if (document.addEventListener) {
    alert("IE9 or greater");
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Duh**... been a few years, since I busted one of these out..

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
  <style>
    #ie { display: block !important;}
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to use this method of detecting if you're using IE?

```
if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) > 8)
    console.log('Using IE9/10'); 
else         
    console.log('Not IE9/10');
```

**Another way of doing it because $.browser is deprecated:**

```js
checkIEVersion();

/**
 * Returns the version of Internet Explorer or a -1
 * (indicating the use of another browser).
 */
function getIEVersion()
{
    var returnValue = -1; // Return value assumes failure.

    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
    {
        var userAgentValue = navigator.userAgent;
        var regExpValue  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
        if (regExpValue.exec(userAgentValue) != null)
            returnValue = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
    }

    return returnValue;
}

function checkIEVersion()
{
    var returnMessage = "You're not using Internet Explorer.";
    var ieVersion = getIEVersion();

    if ( ieVersion > -1 )
    {
        if ( ieVersion >= 9.0 ) 
            returnMessage = "You're using a recent copy of Internet Explorer."
        else
            returnMessage = "You should upgrade your copy of Internet Explorer.";
    }

    console.log( returnMessage );
}
```

Comment: "msie  is undefined"??

Comment: Yeah, you could also use the [jQuery Migrate plugin](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/08/jquery-migrate-1-2-1-released/) too