# Facebook login (from Like button) stuck after entering credentials

Tags: javascript, facebook, mobile, facebook-login, qr-code

I have embedded the Facebook Javascript SDK in my website as well as a like button for a specific facebook page.

When a user clicks the like button and wasn't logged into Facebook, their login process triggers. This works fine in desktop browsers and recent Chrome/Safari versions for mobile devices.

I do, however, need to use QR codes to get people to my site. Some QR code reader apps open URLs in their own crippled browsers (e.g. "QR Code Reader" for Android).
These browsers get stuck after someone enters the credentials and clicks "Login" (the URL at this point is extremly long, starting with "https://www.facebook.com/plugins/close_popup.php?reload=https..."). Could this be due to their lack of tabs?

Is there any way to fix this or can I at least check the user's browser (in Javascript) and show them a message, that they should open this page in a current version of e.g. Chrome/Safari?

**edit:**
Okay, I somewhat got it to work by using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2401861/3653719) and only allowing certain detected browser versions (Safari & Chrome 4+, Opera, IE 10+). It's not ideal and seems fragile, but it works for now. I'd still prefer the login working on those browsers, though. :/