# How to target a javascript function only to safari < 6.0 on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile-safari, turbolinks

I am using a library which has a bug for safari 5.1+ until 5.9 on iOS (mobile) but it work fine after 6.0 (6.0 included) on iOS.

The library in question does allow to remove the element that generates the bug:

```
Turbolinks.ProgressBar.disable();
```

How can I say to javascript to apply the function removeProgressBar **only** to **safari <6.0 (strict inferiority) on iOS** :

```
function removeProgressBar {
  Turbolinks.ProgressBar.disable();
}
```

Important:

- Safari 6.0 and safari  6.0+must not be affected on iOS nor on desktop (OS X) (I don't want to remove progress bar in this case)
- safari 5.1.x **on desktop (OS X)**  must not be affected  (I don't want to remove progress bar in this case)
- not sure if it matters but I am using bootstrap 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this post: [Browser detection in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript). It has some useful information on detecting browser and version. Be careful though, because this can never be 100% reliable.

Comment: thanks but it seems the question and answser enable to detect a browser but NOT its version and not whether it's on iOS or desktop. which are 2 specific needs of my question.

Comment: I don't think what your trying to do is possible, your better off trying to use sonething else that provides more support.

Comment: actually it's too structural for my app, prefer to keep it. in fact your link's accepted answre by kennebec would enable me to find browser and version . I then have to find a way to detect if user is on iOS or desktop:)

Comment: Glad to help, hope all goes well :)