# Hide/Show element if IE - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working with a script that pops up an `alert` if the user is or isn't using IE.

Instead of this, I'd like to show or hide a `div` element in my page.

I have tried unsuccessfully here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/shhv1Lx3/2/

**Working alert demo here:** http://fiddle.jshell.net/shhv1Lx3/3/

```js
function GetIEVersion() {
  var sAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
  var Idx = sAgent.indexOf("MSIE");

  // If IE, return version number.
  if (Idx > 0) 
    return parseInt(sAgent.substring(Idx+ 5, sAgent.indexOf(".", Idx)));

  // If IE 11 then look for Updated user agent string.
  else if (!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)) 
    return 11;

  else
    return 0; //It is not IE
}

var e = document.getElementById(ie);
var e2 = document.getElementById(chrome);

if (GetIEVersion() > 0) 
   alert("This is IE " + GetIEVersion());
   e.style.display = 'block';
   e2.style.display = 'none';
else 
   alert("This is not IE.");
   e.style.display = 'none';
   e2.style.display = 'block';
```

```html
<div id="ie">
ie
</div>

<div id="chrome">
chrome
</div>
```

Comment: does the alert work?

Comment: no brackets in that `if` statement

Comment: You need `{}` brackets on multiline ifs

Comment: Overall, two (or three) problems that would have been completely avoided using the most basic of looking at the console. It reported (correctly) that the `else` statement is wrong because it didn't match any `if`s, it also complains about `e` being `null` and if that error was fixed, it would thrown the same error about `e2` as well. We see these sorts of rookie mistakes dozens of times a day here at SO but usually from...well, rookies. I'd have thought that a member of 5 years over 2k rep would 1. have the basic skills to avoid them 2. not run over to SO to ask for debugging help.

Comment: @TankorSmash Thank you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `{}` when using `if`/`else` statements.  The are *optional* when there is only one statement, but *mandatory* when there are multiple statements.  I ***highly*** suggest using `{}` always, regardless of the number of statements.

You also need to pass a *string* to `getElementById()`.

```js
function GetIEVersion() {
  var sAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
  var Idx = sAgent.indexOf("MSIE");

  // If IE, return version number.
  if (Idx > 0){
    return parseInt(sAgent.substring(Idx+ 5, sAgent.indexOf(".", Idx)));
  }
  // If IE 11 then look for Updated user agent string.
  else if (!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)){
    return 11;
  }
  else{
    return 0; //It is not IE
  }
}

var e = document.getElementById('ie');
var e2 = document.getElementById('chrome');

if (GetIEVersion() > 0){
   alert("This is IE " + GetIEVersion());
   e.style.display = 'block';
   e2.style.display = 'none';
}
else{
   alert("This is not IE.");
   e.style.display = 'none';
   e2.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<div id="ie">
ie
</div>

<div id="chrome">
chrome
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have made this updates here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/shhv1Lx3/4/ but it still seems to be displaying both divs :(

Comment: Rocket by name, Rocket by nature - what speed! :-D Thank you

Comment: @michaelmcgurk: Check your `getElementById()` lines.  You need to pass them *strings*.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk check the JavaScript console and the reason becomes clear `TypeError: e is null`.

Comment: As the `.indexOf()` method is not supported in all IE versions, I recommend using the `.match()` method instead.

Answer (score 4):

You could easily accomplish this (IE vs. not IE) without Javascript using conditional IE comments

```
<!--[if IE ]>
  <style>
    #chrome { display: none; }
  </style>

  <div id="ie">
    ie
  </div>
<![endif]-->
<div id="chrome">
  chrome
</div>
```

**Note** This will only work for IE9 and below - if you are using standards or quirks mode in IE10 or above conditional comments will not work. [Read more here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: That's a very clean approach - I like it!

Comment: Though conditional comments are [not supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx) in IE10 and later.

Comment: @Teemu in standards and quirks mode (which most people would probably opt for - just wanted to clarify a bit). Thanks for the comment though, will update my answer

Answer (score 3):

When you have multiple statements in an `if` or `else`, you need to wrap them in curly braces.

```
if (GetIEVersion() > 0) {
   alert("This is IE " + GetIEVersion());
   e.style.display = 'block';
   e2.style.display = 'none';
} else {
   alert("This is not IE.");
   e.style.display = 'none';
   e2.style.display = 'block';
}
```

[Why is it considered a bad practice to omit curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces?lq=1)

Comment: Unbelievable. This is common syntax in most programming languages. Are you normally a Python programmer? It's the only common language that uses indentation instead of brackets.

Comment: @Barmar: Or he could just use used to the syntactic sugar of being able to omit them for single lines inside `if`/`else`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like syntax errors

```
if (GetIEVersion() > 0)  {
   alert("This is IE " + GetIEVersion());
   e.style.display = 'block';
   e2.style.display = 'none';
   }
else { 
   alert("This is not IE.");
   e.style.display = 'none';
   e2.style.display = 'block';
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had **great success** with the following code snippet from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2401861/5076162) Stack Overflow answer to detect Chrome:

I have tested and it works just fine for Internet Explorer.

It avoids the `.indexOf()` methodology which I prefer.  You would simply replace the search parameter in the regex with *MSIE*

```
var detectID = (function() {
  var ua = navigator.userAgent,
    tem,
    M = ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
  if (/trident/i.test(M[1])) {
    tem = /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
    return 'IE ' + (tem[1] || '');
  }
  if (M[1] === 'Chrome') {
    tem = ua.match(/\b(OPR|Edge)\/(\d+)/);
    if (tem != null) return tem.slice(1).join(' ').replace('OPR', 'Opera');
  }
  M = M[2] ? [M[1], M[2]] : [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
  if ((tem = ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i)) != null) M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);
  return M.join(' ');
})();

if (detectID.match("IE") || detectID.match("MSIE") ) {
  console.log("IE Browser Detected: " + detectID);
} else {
  console.log("Not IE: " + detectID);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, Alexander for taking the time to reply with this detailed response - greatly appreciated :-)