# Show a single web page only to people with Chrome 18

Tags: javascript, html

Hi how i can make show a web page only to people with chrome 18 ? , and if they do not have chrome 18 the page should not be displayed , how can I create something like this using a html code ?
and also if they have firefox or safari the webpage must not be appear

Comment: I think you'll need javascript for this, as in the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browser detection in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

1) Put the content you want to only show to Chrome 18 users in a `<div>`, with `display: none;` in its style:

```
<div id="hiddenContent" style="display: none;">
    My hidden content.
</div>
```

2) Add a `<script>` tag, with the following code:

```
function GetChromeVersion() {     
    var raw = navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrom(e|ium)\/([0-9]+)\./);
    return raw ? parseInt(raw[2], 10) : false;
}
if (GetChromeVersion() == 18)
    document.getElementById("hiddenContent").style.display = "";
```

Here's a live example:

```html
<div id="hiddenContent" style="display: none;">
My hidden content.
</div>

<script>
function GetChromeVersion() {     
    var raw = navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrom(e|ium)\/([0-9]+)\./);
    return raw ? parseInt(raw[2], 10) : false;
}
if (GetChromeVersion() == 18)
    document.getElementById("hiddenContent").style.display = "";
</script>
```