# How do I target all browsers except for IE and Edge

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've gotten a 3d model animation working but the css file is quite big. Here's my plan. I'm going to separate the css file from the 3d model and only important that css when that browser is not EDGE and not IE. Edge and IE extremely struggle with the animations I'm working with. Is there a way to target everything but edge? It can be a combination, it can be multiple queries. I'd prefer to do this without js, but if a js solution is optimal, I'll use it.

ideally it would look something like this:

```
(if not edge or ie query) {@import url("3dmodel.css");}
```

or if I can't select no edge or ie specifically something like this:

```
(if chrome query) {@import url("3dmodel.css");}
(if firefox query) {@import url("3dmodel.css");}
(if ...){...}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browser detection in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript)

Answer (score -2):

I hope this helps your needs [browser specific css](https://www.wired.com/2010/02/browser-specific_css_hacks/)

Comment: Avoid link-only answers - links can go dead.