# How to detect if browser is Internet Explorer or Microsoft Edge and if so, redirect it too another website?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, microsoft-edge

I am new to this so please go easy - I need to redirect a website because the video background I'm using won't play on Internet Explorer or Microsoft Edge. So I'm hoping to redirect it elsewhere. Could anyone with more knowledge than me write this in Javascript for me? I would be really appreciative.

Comment: We will be glad to help if you get stuck on a specific programming problem, but we are not here to write code or design your system for you. You will need to at least make an attempt at solving your own issue. Please see [ask] a good question and [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) After [doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you detect the version of a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/how-can-you-detect-the-version-of-a-browser) and [Browser detection in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935)

Comment: If video background is not playing than you need to find the reason that why it is not playing in IE or Edge instead of redirecting to other site. try to check the console for any error or warning message. Try to check the code whether it is supported by IE and Edge or not. If it is supported than try to make a sample code that can produce the issue on our end and try to post it here. than we will try to test it and try to find the issue in it and try to provide you the suggestions to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use window.navigator API to check the browser and throw in a popup/alert which cannot be closed.

Please refer to this [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/navigator).