# Is there a way to retrieve the default search engine from a Chrome browser's settings?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, event-tracking

I am creating a Chrome extension that tracks multiple events periodically such as the current date, the extension's install Id, etc. One particular event I want to keep track of is the browser's current default search engine. The extension has no popup so there is no user interaction.

That being said, the only way I can think of getting that information is from the browser's settings page. Is there any API or other logic I can use in JavaScript to achieve this?

Comment: Have you checked [this SO post (Browser detection in JavaScript?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript)? It could be related to the functionality you need.

Comment: You'll probably have to write a separate external utility to check the browser preferences file directly and report back via nativeMessaging API.