# Make a certain div show when the user's browser is detected

Tags: javascript

(UPDATED)
I am trying to make a certain div show when the user's browser is detected. I found the code online and am not sure if it even works or how to put a div in the certain browser sections of the code.

```js
<script>
   function BrowserDetection() {
  if(!navigator || !navigator.userAgent) {
    // Insert condition for old browsers
  }
  else if (navigator.userAgent.search("MSIE") >= 0) {
    // Insert conditional IE code here
  }
  else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") >= 0) {
    alert('code');
  }
  else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox") >= 0) {
    // Insert conditional Firefox Code here
  }
  //Check if browser is Safari
  else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Safari") >= 0 && navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") < 0) {
    // Insert conditional Safari code here
  }
  //Check if browser is Opera
  else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Opera") >= 0) {
    // Insert conditional Opera code here
  }
}
</script>
```

This one does not seem to work. Would anyone know where I could possibly find a working code. Thank you very much..

Comment: @byxor tried to fix the code, but Chrome was `& lt; <` for some reason... I hope this was just a pasting issue.

Comment: Could you share where you found the code? And can you share the errors you are getting in your console when you run this code?

Comment: If I were you I'd look at [browser detection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14862119/5601284) and [appendChild](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) (for inserting elements into the webpage)

Comment: The errors https://repl.it/repls/ThoseAuthenticComputergames And the code https://www.learningjquery.com/2017/05/how-to-use-javascript-to-detect-browser

Comment: You're trying to run the javascript code through a java compiler. They're 2 different languages.

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/FrighteningDearestSquare

Comment: You can't use repl.it for this. It runs NodeJS on a server, rather than running the javascript in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

basically, there is a `window.navigator` object in browsers that gives information about the browser.

The above code should be updated to check if this `navigator` object exists before trying to access the userAgent.

ALSO, `&GT;` is not a valid comparison operator, replace it with `>=`

```
function BrowserDetection() {
  if(!navigator || !navigator.userAgent) {
    // Insert condition for old browsers
  }
  else if (navigator.userAgent.search("MSIE") >= 0) {
    // Insert conditional IE code here
  }
  else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") >= 0) {
    // Insert conditional Chrome code here
  }
  else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox") >= 0) {
    // Insert conditional Firefox Code here
  }
  //Check if browser is Safari
  else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Safari") >= 0 && navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") < 0) {
    // Insert conditional Safari code here
  }
  //Check if browser is Opera
  else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Opera") >= 0) {
    // Insert conditional Opera code here
  }
}
```

Comment: We are not sure if this is a pasting issue or not.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl she already commented below that the code has 9 errors, I am assuming one for each comparator, and others

Comment: Ok, that was on a deleted post... I will revert the code then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect it using F12 and check if you can see that div in your sources code. Then add debugger to it and try checking your functionality.