# Determine the browsers homepage

Tags: php, javascript

I've searched for an answer but I can't seem to find out how this is done.  Obviously I know that access to the browsers homepage is a security issue and not easily obtained, but I want to know if there is a way we can compare it.

If you search for something on Google in Internet Explorer and click on page 2, then hit the refresh button, you'll see a blue bar appears that says "Come Here Often? Make Google your Homepage".  My questions is, how is this accomplished?

I've tried putting in an iFrame that contains an HTML file that has `window.location = "about:home";` But, that doesn't work because it will just keep reloading the page if I am the homepage...

Hopefully someone out there can help me out with a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending user to their browser's Home Page using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369450/sending-user-to-their-browsers-home-page-using-javascript)

Comment: about:home does not work in Google Chrome btw.

Comment: Not sure for this, maybe a validation to see if the iFrame is not set to your page, if it is, then just stop it? Also, in browser other than IE, you should use window.home().

Comment: I should have been more specific.  I only want this to work in IE, hence the "about:home".  I know how to send a user to their homepage, I just want to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

For most browsers, window.home(); will work.

For most flavors of IE, window.location.href = "about:home";