# Find a browser's homepage

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.1

We have a requirement to identify the homepage setting of a visitor's browser when he visits our site. Is this even possible?

I need this functionality for something similar to "Come here often? Make Google your homepage". How do you propose we do it? Using cookies? How can a cookie tell me that my site is the home page or not?

Comment: Wow, I sure hope it isn't possible. What a terrible invasion of privacy.

Comment: I don't think so.. that would be a security issue for certain. You might be able to pull it off client side.

Comment: Pointy haired boss requesting it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1369450/334121.

Comment: Google does it, don't they? When you don't have Google set as your homepage, they sometimes put a little message at the top that says something like "Come here often? Make Google your homepage." How do they do it if it isn't possible?

Comment: @Travesty3: They detect the *absence* of their own Google cookie.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Ah, so you can't really tell what their homepage is, but you can sort of tell whether or not it's you. Thanks for solving that little mystery for me. Makes sense as to why I can't get that message to come back up now by changing my homepage to someone else. The cookie is still there because it was my homepage before.

Comment: @anxiety Thank you. The methods listed in that link did not work.

Comment: I need this functionality for something similar to - "Come here often? Make Google your homepage". How do you propose we do it? Using Cookies? How can a cookie tell me that my site is home page or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. It's too intrusive.

On a side note, may I ask why you are doing it?

Comment: Not in an answer, you can't. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, that's is not possible. That would be an intrusion of privacy.