# Sending user to their browser's home page using HTML

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am designing a support website which requires a "Quick Hide Site" button in a prominent position. I have created one using the following code on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5txornMnk03XBtkL5FXx?p=preview)

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Support Site</h1>
    <a class="hide" href="http://www.google.co.uk">Quick Hide Site</a>
  </body>

</html>
```

**css**

```
.hide{
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    display:block;
    font-size:15px;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:0.9em;
    position:fixed;
    top:145px;
    right:0px;
    background-color:tomato;
    width:50px;
    padding:8px 3px 6px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    box-shadow:0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    text-transform:uppercase;
    z-index:999999;
}
```

As some people don't use Google and have a different home page set in their browser, can I change the hyper-link in the html coding to get the visitor to go to their home page set in their browser instead of Google?

I have found [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369450/sending-user-to-their-browsers-home-page-using-javascript) in StockOverflow but where I am not familiar with JavaScript, I don't know how I would use the coding.

Comment: If you seriously do not understand or are able to implement the clear script in the answer you posted, then I do not see how we can help. There is no way in plain HTML to redirect a browser

Comment: "I am not familiar with JavaScript" well, there's your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the link says

1. Identify the type of browser the user is in, using javascript.
2. Call the function to redirect the user to their homepage, again - using javascript

This [link](http://www.mail-archive.com/jquery-en@googlegroups.com/msg35006.html) shows you exactly what code you need

Comment: solution no longer works on chromium-based browsers, no "window.home", no "about:home"