# Getting website before or home page

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to get the url of the website the user was on before loading the current website or just a quick way to redirect to it? I understand there is `document.referrer` but I need something more ubiquitous.

Also, is there any way to get the users browser home page (or any of the browser settings for that matter)? Now, I don't need the exact URL but a means to, for example, a user to click on a button and get redirected to his homepage.

I understand there are many security concerns over this, but really anything will do.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  Just curious.

Comment: How's about JavaScript's history object?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369450/sending-user-to-their-browsers-home-page-using-javascript

Comment: @PatrickHofman: `window.home()` seems to only work in Firefox.  It doesn't work in Chrome.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I would like to test it for UX reasons. For example, the user would be redirected to the last site/ he visited after he hits the logout button. Or his homepage.

Comment: @user3525134: Personally, I don't think I'd like that "feature", but that's just me.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: I was just typing the same...

Comment: You might be able to use [`window.history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) for your needs.  As for getting/redirecting to the homepage, not many browsers browsers support that.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I think neither would I. It is a client wish. And a test is exactly that, an assessment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function goBack()
  {
  window.history.go(-2)
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="goBack()">Go 2 pages back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_history.asp)

But Why?

Comment: For UX purposes. I guess I will need to track how many times the user has clicked on a link within the website and then use this number in the back function. Thanks.